# Getting justgage to work with angular material

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, justgage

I am trying to get just gage to work with angular material. I have followed the setup instructions provided in just gage site. Below is the code pen link. Would like to know where I'm going wrong.

```
<div id="gauge" class="200x160px"></div>
<script>
  var g = new JustGage({
    id: "gauge",
    value: 67,
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    title: "Visitors"
  });
    </script>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JKWORP

Comment: That CodePen is showing lots of errors in the console.

Comment: Hi! Could you try the solution of my answer?

Comment: It worked.. Thanks troig...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @camdem_kid posts in a comment, your codepen is showing lots of errors. So, I've decidded to create a plunker from scratch where you can see working together `angular-material` and `justgage`.

> See working
>   [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/DYJML9EGbAwHpEwfZSkf?p=preview)

Just for reference (see the plunker for the complete details)

```
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.css">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0-rc2/angular-material.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>

  <script src="raphael-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="justgage.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-app="YourApp" class="main_content">

  <div id="gauge" class="200x160px"></div>

  <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <md-button class="md-raised">Hello</md-button>
  </div>

  <script>
    var g = new JustGage({
      id: "gauge",
      value: 67,
      min: 0,
      max: 100,
      title: "Visitors"
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Hope it helps.